Why is coeffecient of restitution only along the Normal direction and not along the Tangential direction?
Up until now I was using coefficient of restitution $e$ for 1D collisions easily,but now in 2D collisions $e$ is only applied along the normal direction to the collision,and not in the tangential direction of the collision.Why is this happening?

Which is the direction of the velocity that is mostly reversed?

because the collision is towards  the normal direction

The "coefficient of restitution" approach to collisions is an approximate way to describe a more complicated material interaction (refer to "Hertz Contact Theory" for additional info).  Most high school and undergraduate courses only deal with a single coefficient because it is a simple way to learn the concept, even though it is an over-simplification.  But there are actually other more advanced ways to describe collision dynamics, including at least one way that uses two coefficients - one normal and one tangential.
For more details, see "A New Algebraic Rigid Body Collision Law Based On Impulse Space Considerations" by Chatterjee and Ruina.
http://ruina.tam.cornell.edu/research/topics/collision_mechanics/new_algebraic_rigid_body.pdf
